# Round a decimal in VB

Tags: decimal, rounding, basic

have a project where I need to round a decimal.
FOR EXAMPLE

```
                        Dim valox As Decimal
                        valox = 13.946
```

i have to round this number to 13.95

i tried this

```
       Decimal.Round(valox, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

but the value gives me 13.94

how do i do this?

Comment: You are using `Round` with 3 but then asking why it doesn't round to 2 decimal places. Also, what is with all of the unnecessary indentation? Please make your question more readable. Finally, why not tag with the correct dialect of basic?

Comment: sorry now i made the question in a more clear way

Comment: Just tried [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_vb_compiler)  your code and the result is 13.95 (also without `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`)

Comment: can you paste code ? because it keeps giving me 13.94

Comment: Dim valox As Decimal
valox = 13.946
Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Round(valox, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))